# Force simulation of texts on bubble-chart does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, bubble-chart

I have a script in which I make circles and then append text to them. I want to use force simulation so that texts of different circles don't overlap.

The issue that I am currently facing is shown in graph below: (2 red circles on the left have overlapping text)[image]

I used force simuation in my script for texts but nothing happens. I am not getting any error but still the texts are overlapping.  I have tried many solution but nothing seems to work.

Following is my script:

```
 function graph(data){
    //var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50}

    var margin = 40,
    width = 600,
    height = 400;

    //   var force = d3.layout.force()
        // .nodes(datas)
        // .size([width, height]);

    simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("x", d3.forceX())
        .force("y", d3.forceY())
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(20)); 

    var xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return +d.student_percentile;
        })])
        .nice() 
        .range([0, width]);

    var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                return +d.rank;
            })])
            .nice()
            .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xscale).tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d > 100 ? "Not Available" : d
    });

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yscale);

    var svg = d3.select('.chart')
        .classed("svg-container", true)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'chart')
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 680 490")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
        .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var local = d3.local();
    circles = svg.selectAll(null)
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", width / 2)
          .attr("cy", height / 2)
          .attr("opacity", 0.3)
          .attr("r", 20)
          .style("fill", function(d){
            if(+d.admit_probability <= 40){
                return "red";
            }
            else if(+d.admit_probability > 40 && +d.admit_probability <= 75){
                return "yellow";
            }
            else{
                return "green";
            }
          })
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return xscale(+d.student_percentile);
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return yscale(+d.rank);
          })
          .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
            local.set(this, d3.select(this).style("fill"));
            d3.select(this)
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .ease(d3.easeBounce)
              .attr("r", 32)
              .style("cursor", "pointer")
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
              var d = this.__data__;
              show_details(d);
            }
           )
          .on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", local.get(this));
            d3.select(this).transition()
              .style("opacity", 0.3)
              .attr("r", 20)
              .style("cursor", "default")
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .ease(d3.easeBounce);
            remove_details();
          });

    texts = svg.selectAll(null)
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.abbreviation;
      })
      .attr("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "12px")
      .attr("fill", "black");

  simulation.nodes(data).on("tick", function(){
        texts.attr("x", function(d) {
             return xscale(+d.student_percentile);
           })
             .attr("y", function(d) {
             return yscale(+d.rank);
           });
    });


  //        force.on("tick", function() {

  //   texts.attr("x", function(d) { return +d.student_percentile; })
  //       .attr("y", function(d) { return +d.rank; });

  // });


    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Percentile");

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Rank");

    $('circle').tipsy({ 
        gravity: 'w', 
        html: true, 
        title: function() {
            var d = this.__data__;
            return d.name + '<br/> Rank: ' + d.rank + '<br/> Admit Probaility: ' + d.admit_probability + '%'; 
        }
    });
}
```

I even tried doing:

```
 simulation.nodes(data).on("tick", function(){
        texts.attr("x", d3.forceX().x(function(d) {
             return xscale(+d.student_percentile);
           }))
             .attr("y", d3.forceY().y(function(d) {
             return yscale(+d.rank);
           }));
    });
```

This also does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to provide a working answer without seeing your data or a minimum running code. But some mistakes are obvious, and this is a general solution:

First, you have to specify the positions you want for the texts in the `forceY` and `forceX` functions:

```
simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
        return xscale(+d.student_percentile);
    }))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
        return yscale(+d.rank);
    }))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(20));
```

Then, in the `tick` function, you just use the `x` and `y` properties created by the simulation:

```
simulation.nodes(data).on("tick", function() {
    texts.attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return d.y;
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. What you have provided solves the issue to some extent but the values are not scaled properly in this way. This is the link to my script: https://jsfiddle.net/ngfoha56/
Many bubbles are going even beyond X=100 with values of X as say 92 and the ones with X=100 are getting cut down from sides and values with X=100 are coming before 100. Basically, I feel there is some issue with scaling.

Comment: Also, some texts still overlap

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. Apologies for inconvenience. The bubbles in my actual graph, get cut from the right most corner. 
On inspecting the graph, I get cx="630.079176853747" and cy="48.48043546247491". So, the circle gets cut down and is tus not visible properly

Comment: I even tried doing 
circles.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); });

as mentioned in this link: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492

Still, does not work :(

Comment: Basically, as values of same X-axis values are increasing, circles are getting cut down. Like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ngfoha56/7/
I have added 2 more elements H an I of same X-Axis value as that of G, so D element is getting cut from sides!
I want to keep these bounded

Comment: You have to apply the force **only to the texts**: https://jsfiddle.net/02heuL98/ Regarding other issues, please don't ask further questions in the comments: if you have other issues, just post a **new** question.